# $-(p(x)f'(x))'=\lambda f$ for positive functions $p(x)>0$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

Do you know any example of a positive on ${\mathbb R}$ and a bounded function $p(x)>0$ for which all solutions of Sturm–Liouville equation are known (ie some formula)?

$-(p(x)f'(x))'=\lambda f(x)$

I am specifically interested in the case $p(x)=e^{-x^2}$, but any example is of interest.

Comment: Just so you know, if you can't find exactly what you are after, then you could always derive the solution yourself using a series expansion of $f$.

Comment: $p(x)=1$ is such a known case.

Answer (score 1):

$$-(p(x)f'(x))'=k f$$
See for example: $p(x)=x^2$, the the ODE is
$$x^2f''+2xf'+kf=0$$
This is Eular's homogeneous ODE. Take $f=x^m$, then you get
$m(m-1)+2m-k=0 \implies k=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4k}}{2}=m_1,m_2$
So the solution is $$f(x)
=C_1 x^{m_1}+ C_2 x^{m_2}$$

Comment: What about boundedness? $x^2$ is not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

You can assume a power series in $\lambda$:
$$
               f_{\lambda}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^n g_n(x).
$$
This will yield a solution of $Lf_{\lambda}=\lambda f_{\lambda}$, where
$$
                Lf = -(pf')'.
$$
Substituting:
$$
          \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^nLg_n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^{n+1}g_n,
$$
which implies that $Lg_n=g_{n-1}$ for $n \ge 1$ and $Lg_0=0$. To satisfy particular endpoint conditions, you may choose to specify conditions for $g_0$, and then choose $0$ endpoint conditions for $g_n$, $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. That is,
$$
                       g_0(0)=A, \;\;\; g_0'(0)=B,\\
                       g_n(0)=0,\;\; g_n'(0)=0,\;\;\; n \ge 1.
$$
In your case, $Lf = -(e^{-x^2}f')'$. So $g_0(x)$ must satisfy
$$
                       (e^{-x^2}g'_0)'=0, \\
                         g_0(0)=A,\;\; g_0'(0)=B.
$$
Therefore,
$$
                    e^{-x^2}g_0'(x) = B \\
                    g_0'(x) = Be^{x^2} \\
                    g_0(x) = A+B\int_{0}^{x}e^{x^2}dx
$$
Next, $Lg_1 = g_0$ is solved subject to $g_1(0)=g_1'(0)=0$. That is,
$$
                 -(e^{-x^2}g_1')' = g_0,\\ g_1(0)=0,\; g_1'(0)=0.
$$
This is solved by direct integration:
$$
                   -e^{-x^2}g_1'(x) = \int_0^x g_0(x_0)dx_0 \\
       g_1(x) = -\int_0^{x}e^{x_1^2}\int_0^{x_1} g_0(x_0)dx_0  dx_1
$$
The above establishes the recursion that you need in order to solve for the series $f_{\lambda}(x)$ given at the top. Your integrals are going to involve Gaussians, which means you're not going to be able to explicitly perform the integrations.

Comment: Very interesting approach! Can you give any links?
The operator $f\to -(e^{-x^2}f')'$ is positive self adjoint and elliptic. So its spectrum should be discrete. How to deduce the equation on $\lambda$ in your approach?

Comment: Or, am I wrong?

Comment: @qwerty43 : There is a question of whether or not it is enough to require $f, Lf \in L^2$. Or, must you impose some kind of condition on $f$ near $\pm\infty$. The first case is where the operator is essentially self-adjoint.

Comment: Functions $g_i$ computed in this iterative fashion are growing very rapidly. Can this be that the series will converge only for $\lambda=0$.

Comment: @qwerty43 : I don't believe there are any convergence issues.